# Magento email template: $_item -> getDescription returns null

Tags: magento, email, templates

### Project

To modify Magento's email templates to include long descriptions

### Magento Version

1.6.2.0

### File being edited

```
app/design/frontend/default/<template name>/template/email/order/items/order/default.phtml
```

Code of interest in this file with line numbers:

```
31 <strong style="font-size:11px;"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getName()) ?></strong>
46 <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getDescription()) ?>
```

### Problem

**$_item -> getName()** works, but **$_item -> getDescription()** returns null

### Debug

Zend dump for **$_item** (showing "name" as defined; "description" as null):

```
array(79) {
["item_id"] => string(3) "584"
["order_id"] => string(3) "398"
["parent_item_id"] => NULL
["quote_item_id"] => string(4) "1951"
["store_id"] => string(1) "1"
["created_at"] => string(19) "2012-06-04 14:15:39"
["updated_at"] => string(19) "2012-06-04 14:16:18"
["product_id"] => string(3) "156"
["product_type"] => string(6) "simple"
["product_options"] => string(140) "a:1:{s:15:"info_buyRequest";a:3:{s:4:"uenc";s:48:"aHR0cDovL2Rldi5hcHBvZ2VlLmNvbS9iYXNlL21hYy5odG1s";s:7:"product";s:3:"156";s:3:"qty";i:1;}}"
["weight"] => string(6) "0.0100"
["is_virtual"] => string(1) "0"
["sku"] => string(9) "MC969LL/A"
["name"] => string(21) "11" MacBook Air 128GB"
["description"] => NULL
["applied_rule_ids"] => NULL
["additional_data"] => NULL
["free_shipping"] => string(1) "0"
["is_qty_decimal"] => string(1) "0"
["no_discount"] => string(1) "0"
["qty_backordered"] => NULL
["qty_canceled"] => string(6) "0.0000"
["qty_invoiced"] => string(6) "0.0000"
["qty_ordered"] => string(6) "1.0000"
["qty_refunded"] => string(6) "0.0000"
["qty_shipped"] => string(6) "1.0000"
["base_cost"] => NULL
["price"] => string(9) "1199.0000"
["base_price"] => string(9) "1199.0000"
["original_price"] => string(9) "1199.0000"
["base_original_price"] => string(9) "1199.0000"
["tax_percent"] => string(6) "7.0000"
["tax_amount"] => string(7) "83.9300"
["base_tax_amount"] => string(7) "83.9300"
["tax_invoiced"] => string(6) "0.0000"
["base_tax_invoiced"] => string(6) "0.0000"
["discount_percent"] => string(6) "0.0000"
["discount_amount"] => string(6) "0.0000"
["base_discount_amount"] => string(6) "0.0000"
["discount_invoiced"] => string(6) "0.0000"
["base_discount_invoiced"] => string(6) "0.0000"
["amount_refunded"] => string(6) "0.0000"
["base_amount_refunded"] => string(6) "0.0000"
["row_total"] => string(9) "1199.0000"
["base_row_total"] => string(9) "1199.0000"
["row_invoiced"] => string(6) "0.0000"
["base_row_invoiced"] => string(6) "0.0000"
["row_weight"] => string(6) "0.0100"
["base_tax_before_discount"] => NULL
["tax_before_discount"] => NULL
["ext_order_item_id"] => NULL
["locked_do_invoice"] => NULL
["locked_do_ship"] => NULL
["price_incl_tax"] => string(9) "1282.9300"
["base_price_incl_tax"] => string(9) "1282.9300"
["row_total_incl_tax"] => string(9) "1282.9300"
["base_row_total_incl_tax"] => string(9) "1282.9300"
["hidden_tax_amount"] => NULL
["base_hidden_tax_amount"] => NULL
["hidden_tax_invoiced"] => NULL
["base_hidden_tax_invoiced"] => NULL
["hidden_tax_refunded"] => NULL
["base_hidden_tax_refunded"] => NULL
["is_nominal"] => string(1) "0"
["tax_canceled"] => NULL
["hidden_tax_canceled"] => NULL
["tax_refunded"] => NULL
["gift_message_id"] => NULL
["gift_message_available"] => string(1) "0"
["base_weee_tax_applied_amount"] => string(6) "0.0000"
["base_weee_tax_applied_row_amnt"] => string(6) "0.0000"
["base_weee_tax_applied_row_amount"] => string(6) "0.0000"
["weee_tax_applied_amount"] => string(6) "0.0000"
["weee_tax_applied_row_amount"] => string(6) "0.0000"
["weee_tax_applied"] => string(6) "a:0:{}"
["weee_tax_disposition"] => string(6) "0.0000"
["weee_tax_row_disposition"] => string(6) "0.0000"
["base_weee_tax_disposition"] => string(6) "0.0000"
["base_weee_tax_row_disposition"] => string(6) "0.0000"
}
```

### Question

Why is description null here?

I've found that changing the product name after the order was placed doesn't change the name in the order, so it appears that the order object has its own data on the product ordered which is separated from the live catalog (which I suppose makes sense: you'd want that information static and unchangeable).

It also makes sense that it wouldn't try to store the long and/or short descriptions for an item every time it's ordered, because of wasted space in the database. But why include the description field just to leave it blank?

Is my only way to get that information to load the catalog/product model, find the product and attribute that I want ([like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10588616/magento-product-getname-empty))?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct in everything. I don't know why they included the `description` field, but it is empty in all of my 250,000 orders.

You can get the description by the following method:

```
$_description = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->load($_item->getProductId())
    ->getDescription();
```

This could well return `null` as would be the case if the product had been deleted.